# Unable to save existing model instance created via _from_json method

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

Method `from_json` of `mongoengine` `ModelClass` used for:

> Converts json data to an unsaved document instance

If i send to a server json with some changed fields and trying to convert in to unsaved document instance, they dont track a `_changed_fields` in model e.g. `_changed_fields` is always empty.

```
data = self.request.data  # json representation of object
model_instance = SomeModel.from_json()
print(model_instance._changed_fields)  # get empty list
```

As i know `.save` method of ModelInstance only save a changed fields and check it in `_changed_fields` property. So if this property is always empty - unable to save model instance created via `from_json` method.

**Question is** - how can i save model instance created from json?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do this?

```
data = self.request.data
model_instance = SomeModel(**data)
print(model_instance._changed_fields)  # should not be empty
model_instance.save()  # should work
```

**Explanations:**

In python, if a function or a class takes arguments (args) and named arguments (kwargs), one can populate them from respectively a list/tuple (my_list) and a dictionary (my_dict).

Requirements:

- The list/tuple **must have as many elements as the number of positional arguments**
- The dictionary can have as many keys/values we want, **but only the ones matching the named arguments will be matched**.

Example:

```
def foo(a, b, c=None, d=1):
    pass

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c=None, d=1):
        pass

my_list = [1, 2]
my_dict = {'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

you can do:

```
test = foo(*my_list, **my_dict)
```

or

```
obj = Foo(*my_list, **my_dict)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Btw, this question for mongoengine, not standart Django ORM.
The problem is - `.save()` method dont actualy SAVE model (like im describe on my question) This happens cuz `.save()` method save only changed fields and track this changes with `_changed_fields` attribute in model. 
And yes, i can just pass to a model creation **kwargs but in this scenario i cant dereference ReferenceField. In your example _changed_fields will not be empty anytime(if you change in or not) if you trying to save a model with reference field in it.